# C3 UI Issue with overflow in subchart (Screenshot attached)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, c3.js

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoDyX.png)The subchart which is shown in the graph in the left side has categories on the y-axis. But it is looking too cluttered.

I tried to modify the c3.js file by doing some modifications in the inline css. It worked. However,modifying the third party library doesnt seem to be the best solution.

Is there any way to hide just the categories from the subchart and not from the main chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide subchart axis at *onrendered* callback:

```
var chart = c3.generate({

    onrendered: function() {
      this.selectChart.selectAll('.c3-axis-x')[0][1].style.display = 'none'
    },
    ...
});
```

This can be more appropriate solution if you don't want to override library CSS.